# How to fade in/out menu children upon hover on parent

Tags: jquery, hover, parent-child

I'm trying to get a basic `fadeIn` the child `ul` of `#access ul li:hover > ul` upon hover and then `fadeOut` upon hover out.  I have this code, but it's not working:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#access ul li").hover(function() {
            jQuery(this).children("ul").fadeIn(500);
        }, function() {
            jQuery(this).children("ul").fadeOut(500);
    });
});
```

The following code works kind of, but is buggy because I'm not affecting just the `this` children:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#access ul li").hover(function() {
            jQuery(this).children("ul").fadeIn(500).animate({top: '-=10'}, 500, function() { });
        }, function() {
            jQuery("#access ul li > ul").fadeOut(500).animate({top: '+=10'}, 500, function() { });
    });
});
```

Does anyone have any idea why the top version isn't working?

Here's the HTML:

```
<nav id="access" role="navigation">
    <div class="menu"><ul>
        <li><a href="#" title="Home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Sample Page">Sample Page</a>
            <ul class='children'>
                <li><a href="#"; title="About Me">About Me</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Another Page">Another Page</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul></div>
</nav>
```

Comment: including the HTML would help.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds strange, this is working fine for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/tAUw4/

```
<div id="access">
    <ul>
        <li>
            Foo
            <ul>
                <li>Foo - 1</li>
                <li>Foo - 2</li>
                <li>Foo - 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            Bar
            <ul>
                <li>Bar - 1</li>
                <li>Bar - 2</li>
                <li>Bar - 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            Baz
            <ul>
                <li>Baz - 1</li>
                <li>Baz - 2</li>
                <li>Baz - 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

$(function () {
    $('#access li').hover(function () {
        $(this).children('ul').fadeIn();
    }, function () {
        $(this).children('ul').fadeOut();
    });
});

ul ul {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Looks like that's pretty much what I have, but it's not working for me.  Also, if it helps, if I replace `fadeIn()` with `animate()`, animate is working with `this` children.  I'm stumped.

Comment: Hmm.. could you create a JSFiddle that replicates your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Without any html it's just going to be guesswork, but I believe the problem is the element being faded in covering the original element that the hover event handler is attached to, or something similar.

Maybe something like this will work:

```
$(function() {
     $("#access ul li").mouseenter(function() {
         $('ul', this).fadeIn(500);
     });
     $("#access ul li > ul:visible").mouseleave(function() {
         $(this).fadeOut(500);

     });
});
```

If some of the `#access ul li ul` elements are visible by default you could try storing the `this` element from the mouseenter in a variable or with jQuery's data, and use that in the mouseleave function to target the correct element.

Best option would of course be to structure your html and css to make it work the regular way.